# ionic 1 onesignal is there a way to know if there is a push notification when open app from background to foreground or launching app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I have an ionic app made with ionic1 and using OneSignal for push notification.
Currently, one signal works well for push notification when:
- app is already open
- app is in background or kill, clicking on the push notification

using these 2 functions handleNotificationReceived and handleNotificationOpened

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
    $state.go('panicalarm');
    console.log("navigate to panicalarm page");
  })


window.plugins.OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened(function(jsonData) {      
    $state.go('panicalarm');
    console.log("navigate to panicalarm page");
  })
```

I am wondering, how do i handle the push notification when launching the app directly or from bringing the app from background to foreground without clicking on the push notification ? Is that possible ?

Comment: I am not familiar with either ionic or onesignal, but on Android you can clear all notifications like this: NotificationManager.cancelAll() I am not certain if this works for push notifications, but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

i would say we can implement this in the following ways :

**Solution 1**: you can Send  push notification every time . Then, if the app is open, ignore/swallow the notification. 
**It seems like a  waste of resource for me**

**Solution 2**: Keep track of the app's state in your own database and only send a push notification if the app isn't transition from the background to foreground. **It Seems to me  overly complex.**

**My Proposed Solution** :Will keep the same code for the foreground and background but when the app will be transition from the Background to the foreground i would be showing the notification icon (Badge Icon) like below (A sample one)

[image]

1. It attracts the User
2. Never distracts
3. will be disappeared after the User has seen the notification

Answer (score 1):

You can try with https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

it helps you to Keep app running in background

Comment: it has this issue - "Infinite background tasks are not official supported on most mobile operation systems and thus not compliant with public store vendors. A successful submssion isn't garanteed.". If app is in background, and open, is it clear there is no way to receive push information ?